# "Object" EXPLAIN "Subject" (O-V-S): What is the name of this structure?

Tags: sentence-construction

Is this correct? I found that the below sentence is like O-V-S.
What is the name of this usage?

> "Beginning with Windows Insiders builds this Summer, we will include an in-house custom-built Linux kernel to underpin the newest version of the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL),” explains Microsoft program manager Jack Hammons.

https://www.theverge.com/2019/5/6/18534687/microsoft-windows-10-linux-kernel-feature

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [quotative inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject%E2%80%93verb_inversion_in_English#Quotative_inversion). "explain" here is acting as a synonym for "said".

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the link :)